# Good practices for getting User's records in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm starting learning Laravel and I wonder about the way to retrieve some data.

I have 4 tables (among others)

- Users
- Records
- RecordsA
- RecordsB

An User may have multiple records. Records has a foreign key of user
RecordsA has a foreign key of Records.
RecordsB has a foreign key of Records

I would like to retrieve records (A or B) from an User and I wonder what is the best way to do it.

1. **Write functions to the user's repository** `getRecordA() and getRecordB()` so that I could do in my controller, `$this->user->getRecordA() and user->getRecordB()`
2. **Write functions to recordA's repository and recordB's repository**. I will inject the id of the user in the query. So in my controller, I would write something like `recordA->get($user)`

I'm asking that, because the user is the core of my app and I have many tables (among Records, RecordsA and RecordsB) that are linked to my user and I'm afraid that my user table will be huge. However, for me it's intuitive to put all the related function to the user repository.

What do you think ? What is the best way to achieve that ?

Thank

Answer (score 1):

Relationships is a good start for your problem. For the first level of records you can use `hasMany()`. Traditionally repositories is used in cases like this, but i think this is more in the idea of a `Laravel` application.

```
class User
{
    public function records() {
        return $this->hasMany(Record::class);
    }
}
```

For your nested records, you should use `hasManyThrough()`.

```
class User
{
    public function recordAs() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(RecordA::class, Record::class);
    }

    public function recordBs() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(RecordB::class, Record::class);
    }
}
```

Now you can access all of your relationships, in a very Eloquent Laravel'sk way. Imagine exposing them to a view or similar.

```
public function show(User $user) {
    return view('show')->with(
        'user' => $user,
        'records' => $user->records,
        'recordAs' => $user->recordAs,
        'recordBs' => $user->recordBs,
    )
}
```

If you need to go deeper relationship wise then the current level, you have to use [third party libraries](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep).

Comment: Thank a lot. Indeed, I have already the hasMany(Record::class) in my User Class. For the HasManyThrough, It's a good idea but do you think, I can get some attributes for my Records table ? Because I need the date_time attribute and it is only available on my Record table and not RecordsA and RecordsB.
Anyway, what you've suggested is to put everything in the User part.

Comment: Please explain this part in detail, im not 100% sure I can get some attributes for my Records table ?

Comment: When I do $this->hasManyThrough(RecordA::class, Record::class), I get only the attribute from RecordA and not Record. I would like to get as well as the same time some attributes like the date_time of Record.
Maybe with Select ?

Comment: when you have recordA cant you just access it through the relationship to its parent, similar to $recordA->parent->date; ?